Anthropic's Claude Haiku model returns not found on Vertex API
I'm trying to use GCP Vertex AI API to use Claude Haiku model and it's returning 404.
the ts code:
const msg = await anthropicVertex.messages.create({
    model: 'claude-3-haiku-20240307',
    max_tokens: 1024,
    messages: [{ role: 'user', content: 'whats up?' }],
  });

error: {
error: {
code: 404,
message: 'Publisher Model projects/modelintano/locations/us-central1/publishers/anthropic/models/claude-3-haiku-20240307 not found.',
status: 'NOT_FOUND'
}
}
